# Are T're Asar split at all?

Tags: number, navi-prophets

We generally consider *T're Asar* as one book (as is evident from [*Bava Basra* 14:2](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3288&size=1)). Are there any ways in which we officially treat it as twelve?

(Possible ways I can think of that we might are: having breaks between the twelve sections of the sort that are normally between *s'farim*, when in a *k'laf* (scroll); a rule that applies only to complete *s'farim* applying also to a scroll containing only one of the twelve (*tum'a* on hands perhaps??); a rule that applies to studying a complete *sefer* applying also to studying only one of the twelve (*siyum b'choros* perhaps??).)

Comment: Toward [the weekly topic challenge](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/752).

Comment: There is (or at least was) a prohibition on writing non-whole-books of Tanakh (YD 283:2). Do you think asking if that prohibition applies/d to sub-books of Trei Asar would be a duplicate of this post?

Comment: @DoubleAA, negative answers there would answer this but positive would not, so IMO no.

Comment: @DoubleAA https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=38728

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a scribe writes a full Tanach on a scroll, he leaves 4 blank lines between books of the Torah and 3 blank lines between books on Nevi'im including between books of Trei Asar. ([Rambam Sefer Torah 7:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=8&perek=7&halocha=15&hilite=), [Shulchan Aruch YD 283:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=473), and I have seen this done when laining a haftorah from a Trei Asar scroll.)

The [Mishna Berurah 144 sk 9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=50) quotes an opinion that prohibits skipping backward to a different book of Nevi'im while reading the Haftorah, even if it is on topic. If I understand him correctly, he extends this ruling to each individual book of Trei Asar.

Comment: BTW regarding your thought about _tum'at yadayim_, any piece of Tanach with at least 85 letters imparts _tum'at yadayim_ per [Yadayim 3:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%92_%D7%94) For comparison, Sefer Ovadiah has about 1100 letters.

Answer (score 7):

Per the [Tshuvos V'Hanhogos 1 Chapter 300](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=214) you can make a Siyum on Yona for example if necessary. This proves that each one of the Trei Asar is a seperate entity.

> אבל בשעת הדחק שאינו מוצא סעודת מצוה בסיום מסכתא יש להקל שילמוד אז עם
>   רש"י ספר נביא כגון : יונה , או מגילת שיר השירים, או מגילת אסתר ,
>   וכדומה עם רש"י ומספיק

Comment: +1: the quoted text implies _Yona_ is considered a separate entity. But your paraphrase of it doesn't imply that: arguably, one can make a _siyum_ on parts of books too.

Comment: @msh210 כגון http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17970/759