# Making a Siyum on major sections of learning but not a codified unit

Tags: halacha, torah-study, siyum

If someone completes a major section of Talmud Torah that is not a formal unit (eg., Basar BeḤalav), may/should one make a Siyum?

Comment: Basar beHalav is not a formal unit? Isn't it the name of a section in YD from somewhere in the 80s to [something a little bigger]?

Comment: @DoubleAA, well, that's what I mean. It's a unit, and certainly a recognized one, but I don't know if it's a _formal_ one.

Comment: So are you asking what is a formal unit? Your question [re: a non formal unit] to me sounded to me like someone learned 15 random simanim in Orach Chaim with Mishna Berura. For some people this might be an accomplishment worth celebrating, and your question would be, can they do so formally?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't see the difference between fifteen random _simanim_ and fifteen _simanim_ that are given a name atop the page. SethJ, are you also asking whether such a _siyum_ counts a _s'udas mitzva_ (e.g. for purposes of meat and wine in the nine days)? If so, you may wish to edit that into your question.

Comment: See piskei Tshuvos 551 which lists a bunch of seforim and the guidlines to what one can make a syium on he mentions there is a shitta which says maybe even a mesechta of mishan is good enough he also brings if one finishs Avos D'Reb Nosson or sifrei Kabbalah,a Rabbi made a syium when he finished Sefer Pri Eitz Chaim. See inside for more on this and the footnotes.

Comment: @msh210 What about [697 simanim](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%96) that have a name atop their page? Is the question asking what formal unit needs to be met, or if the din is one of simcha, both lechumra and lekula?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I mean first of all an actual unit (eg., Shabbath), and if an answer is given that is even more inclusive than that, then that would certainly be suitable.

Comment: @msh210, I am asking for all practical ramifications - including eating meat during the 9 Days and saying Hadran/Kaddish, as well as a firstborn's fasting or not (thanks, DoubleAA).

Comment: @sam, I wish I could look that up.  I haven't got a copy and none seems to be available on Hebrewbooks.org.  Is there a way you can write it up as an answer below, or is it too long and involved for that?

Comment: @SethJ ,it is alot too much to write.

Comment: @Sam Can you list his primary sources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rav Moshe writes in his [Igros Moshe OH 1:157](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=276) that if someone did learn and feels accomplished then that calls for celebration but he also mentions that it took some time and it seems from the tshuva that the mikra was completed and the Rishonim were used for iyun. see inside for mekoros.

Rav Eliyashiv is quoted in the Sefer Va'yishma Moshe and held to be machmir and not make a syium on Nach.

Comment: RYSE held not to celebrate, or not to use it for meat/firstborns/etc.?

Comment: the halacha was said with regard to meat and wine.

Comment: Accepted answer because you brought both sides to the Mikra issue. Have you seen anything on other sections of Talmud Torah, though, like my example in my question?

Comment: In regards to Rav Eliyashuv and Nach....Halacha c'moso?!?! My friend made a siyum on Nach and called a rov to ask what he can say (i.e. hadran, etc.) the Rov said "how did you do it!?" the guy said "with Rashi?" ... He said "no, I mean, *how did you do it*?!? How did you finish all of Nach? I'm jealous of you!!" ... This was a pretty big Rov also...

Comment: 9 days ,what he holds the whole year I don't know.

Comment: @Yehoshua Sounds like a pretty mediocre Rov if he hasn't gone through Nach.

Comment: @doubleaa he probably meant biyum

Answer (score 3):

In [this](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/759904/Rabbi_Shmuel_Marcus/Siyum_Qualifications%3a_What_Must_I_Learn) lecture, the speaker quotes R' Moshe Feinstein that anything that you do that you feel proud of accomplishing — even someone who learned one daf of gemara, if it was hard for him — you can make a siyum on it.

Comment: Does he mention if this type of siyum is 'good enough' for wine/meat during the nine days or to break a firstborn's fast?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think that was the whole question.

Comment: @DoubleAA otherwise what's the chashivas of the siyum!?! (If there is no nafkeh minah)

Comment: @Yehoshua It's a mitzva to honor the Torah and those who learn it.

Comment: @DoubleAA My point was in regards to "dinei siyum" there are many ways to honor the Torah and those that learn it

Comment: @Yehoshua Ok, so I asked if this was just a way to honor Torah and those who learn it, or it was a formal siyum for the Nafka Minah of meat/wine etc.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Guidlines series (by Rabbi Elozor Barclay and Rabbi Yitzchok Jaeger) in both the volume on the 3 weeks and the volume on Pesach say that a siyum to permit breaking the fast of the firstborn and eating meat in 9 days are one of the following:

- A tractate of Talmud
- A seder of Mishna
- A book of Tanach learned b'iyun (b'iyun is not
  defined there)
- A tur of Shulchan Aruch

Comment: What about a tur of the Tur?

Comment: They list only these 4 options.

Comment: Does a "Tur" include Nosei Keilim?

Comment: @SethJ, I'd say no.  Personally I'd consider Nosei Keilim (commentaries) as part of one possible definition of b'iyun.  As such, I'd say one can make a siyum on a section of SA without studying the Shach.  There is presumably extra reward for more study, but not in the form of a siyum.