# Siyum Masechta Ketana

Tags: kaddish, siyum, masechet-derech-eretz

When I celebrate my completion of a [minor tractate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_tractate) (e.g. Masechet Derech Eretz or Kutim or Gerim), should I say [Hadran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadran_%28Talmud%29) and/or Kaddish at my Siyyum (party)?

Comment: Ta Shma': http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17970/5

Comment: @SethJ This is definitely a formal unit. I imagine it would parallel the rules of a completing a tractate of Mishnayot.

Comment: I didn't call it a dupe. I think it's more a Kal VaHomer (from my question to this one) if you follow the answer(s) that you do make a proper Siyum.

Comment: @SethJ It isn't so much of a kal vachomer, since some of them are only one chapter (Avadim); the answer there in the name of R' Moshe Feinstein was that you have to feel accomplished

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rabbi Yechezkel Moskowitz [answers](http://www.shut-halacha.co.il/q/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A-%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-9801) that one may make a full "Siyum" on all "Masechtos Ketanos", except for Maseches Derech Eretz (he quotes the Sefer Yoma Tava, Sha'ar 1, Page 23).

For the exception of Maseches Derech Eretz, he notes the Maharsham to OC 551:10 (image below), which states clearly in the name of the Peri Megadim (Mishbetzos Zahav) and Bach that it is not considered Torah for certain other Halachos:

[image]

This ruling (that one may make a Siyum on a Masechta Ketanah, although he doesn't mention the exception of Derech Eretz) is also stated clearly by the Alei Tamar in his intro to Bava Kama, as well as in Pesachim Perek 10 (text quoted [here](https://www.responsa.co.il/searchg/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%94_page3.aspx)).

[This article](http://www.dvar-tora.co.il/mamr.aspx?id=604) also confirms that a classic "siyum" may be made on these Masechtos, in the name of Rav Ovadiah in Yabia Omer 1:26:10, but I haven't looked that up.

Comment: What's special about Derech Eretz?

Comment: @Heshy no idea - I would suggest looking up the source he quotes.

Comment: @Heshy The source for excluding DE comes from Pri Megadim (§102 MZ n. 4) who bases his opinion on Bach (ibid., cf. gloss to Ber. 20b). IMHO, Bach understands DE not to have same status as other tractates which are primarily of legalistic nature, ergo: fundamentals of Torah.

Comment: @oliver thanks! I'll edit in the Maharsham that he quotes there.