# Siyum Mishnayos on Erev Pesach

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, fast-days, siyum

Today I learned of the minhag to make a siyum bechorim only on gemara. I understand the logic, but is there a source for it? This came up because I'm scheduled to make a siyum on the Mishna (first time on all 6) around Pesach so I volunteered the siyum at my local shtieble.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17970 .

Comment: Not really because shisha sidrei mishna is formally recognized as something you make a siyum on and all editions of the Mishna print a hadran for it even if they don't have one for individual sedarim.

Comment: Read the answers; they're more relevant than the question (though not quite answers to this question). As far making a *siyum* on a *masechta* of *mishnayos*, see the last Rashi on *Shabbos* 118b, who seems to imply that Abaye would make a *Yom Tov* for the rabbis when a scholar completed studying even the *mishnayos* of a *masechta*: דשלים מסכתיה שגרסה. The Maharshal (*Yam Shel Sh'lomo*, *Bava Kama* 7:37) discusses this *gemara* as the source for making a *s'udas mitzva* on finishing a *masechta* (see also *Mishna B'rura* 470:10, who just mentions *maseches* and doesn't specify *gemara*).

Comment: Also, [related comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31817/what-level-of-understanding-is-required-in-learning-for-purposes-of-making-a-s?lq=1#comment82448_31819). R' Ovadia Yosef ruled that making a *siyum* on a *masechta* of *mishnayos* עם פירוש בהבנה is sufficient for *Erev Pesach*.